# Rotate an image in WebBroswer control using C# 2017

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have tried lot of stuff to rotate an image in WebBrowser control using C# windows form application, but no luck to rotate. Could anyone help me to shoot out this.

Comment: How do you display the image in the WebBrowser control? I think you should use some CSS trick.

Comment: I am fetching the image from data table at run time into webbrowser control. Below is the code line how i have bind in controller. 

**webbrowser1.DocumentText = "<img src='" + _currentImage + "' />";**

Comment: _"I have tried lot of stuff"_ - Please show us some of the things you've tried then. Otherwise we might suggest things that you have already tried that didn't work, and this would just turn into a wild-goose chase. Have you tried the CSS [**`transform` property**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String style = @"<style>
img {
transform:          rotate(60deg);
-ms-transform:      rotate(60deg);
-moz-transform:     rotate(60deg);
-webkit-transform:  rotate(60deg);
-o-transform:       rotate(60deg);
}
</style>";

webbrowser1.DocumentText = style +"<img src='" + _currentImage + "' />";
```

Update: 
You have to tell the WebBrowser control which IE version to emulate for you. By default it emulates an old version that does not support rotation. This you can set in the registry. For example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"YourApp.exe"=dword:00002710
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work. But it rotate single position (ie. 60degree). i want to rotate it frequently (from button click, for each click it rotate 90degree). Could you guide me

Comment: I'd recommend fiddling with a html page with css and JavaScript until you achieve the behavior you are looking for. Then take the relevant code and use it in your application.